# Rpivotable - Plotly chart renderers

Tags: javascript, r, flexdashboard, pivottable.js, rpivottable

I have created a pivot table in flexdashboard using a code similar to the following:

```
rpivotTable(Titanic,   rows = c("Survived"),   cols = c("Sex"),    width="100%", height="400px"  )
```

[image]

I would like to have the capability to save the generated output.
Is there a way to modify the code to incorporate the same download, zoom in/out, and other options from Plotly like the following image from https://pivottable.js.org/examples/plotly.html
[image]

Any suggestions on how to do this?